# jQuery to autoplay HTML5 audio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

Ok, so let me tell you where I'm at. The audio file displays and loads. you can click play to play it. The jQuery isn't autoplaying the material. I'm having to load in the file based on the href of the link. Code is below. Trying to get this to autoplay.

```
            $('.voiceLink a', resbox).click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var link = $(this).prop('href'),
                    audio = $('.audioControl', el.parent());

                audio.find('source').prop('src', link);
                audio.parent().css('display','inline-block');
                audio.find('audio').load();
                setTimeout(audio.find('audio').play(), 100);

                $(window).scrollTop();
            });
```

resbox = The wrapper box.

The HTML Element:

```
<div class="audioHide" style="display: none;">
                <div class="audioControl" style="position:relative; top:10px; left:50px; display:inline-block;">
                    <audio controls><source src="#" type="audio/mpeg">
                        Not Supported
                    </audio>
                </div>
                </div>
```

Example Link:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://relatientsounds.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/recordings/2456266.mp3">2456266</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

try this

```
audio.find('source').prop('src', link);
audio.parent().css('display','inline-block');
audio.find('audio').load();
//this line
audio.find('audio')[0].play();
```

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/m25kfy57/1/

Comment: .voiceLink is attached to about 50 different links on the page. It's a table of voice recordings based on a record. They have the ability to click on a Voice Icon to listen to that recording. Clicking on that triggers that function. If it as one link, I'd consider. But I need a way to do it onClick